# Sample code for drawing a spiral in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I searched on Google I found nothing. Do you know some ?

Comment: *@user310291*, could you include some more information in your question, such as What you've tried so far, or where you've got stuck? Is your problem more mathematical in nature, or more XAML/WPF-related? etc.

Comment: Sample code in WPF isn't that clear enough ?!!!

Comment: The point is that people don't typically like to hand people code.  We want to see what you have already tried, your request is just lazy.  This is covered in the FAQ.

Comment: I found my way to the post here from a Google search. The poster omits WHY this is not a straightforward problem in WPF, namely the inability draw images as a set of points. This is a side-effect of the vector based drawing of XAML/WPF. It wasn't laziness on my part looking for a solution of this sort, but rather this stated difficulty. WPF has a ready library of simple curves, arcs, lines, etc. but a spiral shape isn't easily drawn with this without some effort. One method is to draw each point as a line segment of unit length... and I don't have any room left to expand on the rest.

Answer (score 10):

Found the spiral equation ( you have to decide wich one, different kind of spiral exists ) ie: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesSpiral.html that one is presented in polar coordinates. Given so you need to approximate it, for example by lines. This is the way I will go.
So I can post some code just as an example, I wrote in a scratch new wpf application,and I **removed the default grid from the xaml** ( necessary if you want to test soon the code ) :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Path p = new Path();
            p.Data = CreateSpiralGeometry(1000, new Point() { X = 200, Y = 180 },Math.PI*10, 100);
            p.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

            AddChild(p);
        }

        private PathGeometry CreateSpiralGeometry(int nOfSteps, Point startPoint, double tetha, double alpha)
        {
            PathFigure spiral = new PathFigure();
            spiral.StartPoint = startPoint;


            for(int i=0;i<nOfSteps;++i)
            {
                var t = (tetha/nOfSteps)*i;
                var a = (alpha/nOfSteps)*i;
                Point to = new Point(){X=startPoint.X+a*Math.Cos(t), Y=startPoint.Y+a*Math.Sin(t)};
                spiral.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(to,true));
            }
            return new PathGeometry(new PathFigure[]{ spiral});
        }



    }
```

Comment: I also need code in WPF not only algorithm.